# Facebook opening page with play button instead of app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to add facebook to my app on ios. I have configured the facebook app on facebook developer portal i am able to sign in to facebook normaly also i can sent requests which can be viewed by user but when user clicks on the notification then instead of opening my app, facebook opens a page with play button

if user taps on play button then facebook open's my app. while other apps like candy crush, are directly opened by facebook.  Any ideas what might be worng here

I am using latest facebook app for ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was in facebook sdk and it was fixed by facebook team